# Make all variables in a sympy expression positive

Tags: python, sympy

How can I make all the variables in a sympy expression positive numbers? For one variable I know I can do something like this: `x= sympy.symbols('x',positive=True)`, but I would like to do this for all the variables in an expression, without knowing beforehand the variable names i.e. I would like to extract all the variables from the expression and make them positive. How can I do this? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

There is a function specifically for this in sympy:
https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html#posify